# Can't run pyautogui on ubuntu

Tags: python, pyautogui, python-keyboard

i want to use Pyautogui and Keyboard module at the same time (Using Python), but i can't do that. i have installed Keyboard module and Pyautogui module too, but when i try to run Pyautogui via root i get this error (sudo python3)

```
    raise error.DisplayConnectionError(self.display_name, r.reason)
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":1": b'Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified\n'
```

without root, it works. but keyboard doesn't work without root.

```
    raise ImportError('You must be root to use this library on linux.')
ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.
```

I am using .is_pressed() function in keyboard module.

Answer (score 1):

Install `pyautogui` using root:

```
sudo pip install pyautogui
```

Then run your `main.py`:

```
sudo python main.py
```

If the above doesn't work then a better alternative would be `pynput`. `pynput` doesn't require any root permission.

`pynput` example:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    if key.char == "a":
        print(f"alphanumeric key {key.char} pressed")

listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)

listener.start()
```

Output:

```
alphanumeric key a pressed
```

Comment: it's still the same, i have tried that.

Comment: Can you try 2nd line like this `python main.py`?

Comment: Hey, pynput works. but if you know, can you please show me how can i check if key is pressed? thanks!